# IMAGE scaling using XSL:FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I am trying to turn off image scaling when rendering image using XSL:FO. My out put is a A4 size PDFand I am rendering a image ,whose size can vary dynamicly which I dont have control on. I want to display the image as is but xsl:fo is scaling the image and the out put looks inconsistent. I could not find a way to turn off the scaling .

Ideally its better if my image is of the same size if it can be accomodated in the space allocated, if not shrink width and hieght properly
I am using XSLT1.0 and have tried combinations of

```html
<fo:external-graphic height="700pt" width="600pt" 
    content-height="scale-to-fit" content-width="scale-to-fit" 
    scaling="non-uniform"
    src="url('data:$mime;base64,{$src}')"/>

    <fo:external-graphic height="700pt" width="600pt" 
                         content-height="700pt" content-width="600pt" 
                         src="url('data:$mime;base64,{$src}')"/>
```

Comment: If you set width and height .... you are scaling it. Do not set width, height, content-width or content-height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to be left as is *unless" it is too large, then you use:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="myimage.jpg" width="100%" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/>
```

This will take 100% of the area required and if it too large, scale it down (uniformly) in the width direction until it fits.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I am not aware of "scale-down-to-fit". I also want the hieght to be saceled down to fit , is that possible  ?

Comment: You are using display-align, this is centering top to bottom. You want text-align, content-height also takes scale-down-to-fit.

Comment: Also, if your original question is answered, you should mark it as answered and additional questions asked in a new thread,